# Taking long time to return the count of selected options from select box in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a select box with 120000 option values.when I select first option the below method is working fine, but if I select 80000 th option it is taking lot of time and page is getting unresponsive, I am using Jquery 1.3.2 and chrome browser.

```
function getPersonCount(){
var count = $('#[name=PersonNameSelected] :selected').length;
return count;
}
```

Comment: _"I have a select box with 120000 option values"_ o_O

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: `#[name=PersonNameSelected]` is not a valid selector. `#` goes before an ID.

Comment: Seriously, rethink your approach to the problem you're solving. There is no worldly need to have a select box with that many options! Please explain what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to select all the options. When the selected element is a `select-multiple`, `.val()` will return an array of the selected values, which should be more efficient since it doesn't need to create a large jQuery collection.

```
var count = $("[name=PersonNameSelected]").val().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser will become unresponsive with huge data. you can follow workaround, when you select or check an item from multiselect dropdown. At same time, oncheck or onselect you can push that checked/selected item in an array. this way you dont need to get selected items thru jquery selector and in an array you have checked or selected items from dropdown.